# Trying to pick random image from public directory with AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax

Ok, so I'm sorry cause this is probably a basic thing, but I searched everywhere and I don't find anything, so :

-I have a folder with a lot of images in it (+100)

-I want to pick a random one with JavaScript (jQuery is accepted) and do a thing like `document.getElementById("randomImage").setAttribute("src", hrefOfRandomImage)`

-I can't use php

-It's on a server

-There is custom names for all images, so no `var images = ["img1.png", "img2.png"]` + `math.random`

Comment: Need more information. Is this a local directory? Directory on a server somewhere? Do you know how many images you have available? How are they named/organized? There's a variety of solutions based on these questions.

Comment: Oh sorry, I'll edit my post

Comment: Do you have control of the server? Or is it someone else's server?

Comment: Without an array of all the filenames, there's no way to display any image from the server, you need that data with a server side language.

Comment: Declan McKelvey-Hembree: Yes I have control of the server

Comment: Carlos Delgado: But with jQuery and AJAX I've already did things similar